# In Javascript, given two elements that overlap, how to tell which one is above the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to find a function or implementation that given two element nodes that we know overlap given their offsets and width/heights, which one is on top. It's hard to say because we don't know which one is on top given z-index or position.

I've tried using `document.elementFromPoint()`, but that only shows the topmost node at a given coordinate and I just want to check between layers. For example, given three layers, `div1`, `div2`, `div3`, where `div1` is on the topmost layer, I want to see between `div2` or `div3`, which one is on top.

Keep in mind I don't want to check if they overlap -- I know that. I want to check which one is overlapping the other.

Is there a function that already does that so I don't have to reinvent the wheel? Or something I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they don't have a z-index, then they will render in order (assuming they're all positioned). So, if div1 is after div2, div1 will be on top. See here: [Stacking without z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)

Given that, you should be able to check the order based on whether or not the other divs are in `$(element).prevAll()`. Or, sorting them by `$(element).prevAll().length` (where higher numbers are on top).

Comment: Wouldn't there be an issue with position:absolute or fixed, which makes it more complicated?

Comment: Nope, as long as it is positioned (fixed, absolute, relative, etc) with no z-index, they will stack in order. Unpositioned elements will be below the positioned ones.